# How to search embedded mongoid documents with sunspot SOLR?

Tags: mongoid, sunspot

Does anyone know how to index and search [embedded documents](http://mongoid.org/docs/relations/embedded.html) with [sunpot_mongoid](https://github.com/jugyo/sunspot_mongoid)?

The question has been asked in the [sunspot_mongoid issues](https://github.com/jugyo/sunspot_mongoid/issues/9), but has no solution, so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just tried it. It's a hack, but it works for searching embedded documents, and returning the parent document holding it. Is that what you want? If so, do this then. Define method that returns the embedded fields you want as an array, and then index that array.

Assuming you have class Company, with embedded departments

```
searchable do
  # Your regular index
  # ...
  text :company_departments
end

def company_departments
  departments.map(&:name).join(" ")
end
```

reindex and try to search.

Answer (score 1):

You can also include a block that returns the text you want index right in the searchable block. For example:

```
searchable do
    text :innerdoc do
      innerdocs.map { |i| i.title + ' ' + i.description }
    end
end
```

That takes the title and description from an embedded array of "innerdocs" and adds it to the index for the main document.

The sunspot docs have the best info on the syntax for the "searchable" block:
http://outoftime.github.com/sunspot/docs/